Does China or some Chinese entity with influence in Chinese government/SOE decisions rank countries for corruption?
I'm curious if corruption, which China itself sometimes publicly fights against, is considered a yardstick for China or at least its state-owned enterprises investing abroad.
So, does China or some Chinese-based entity rank foreign countries for corruption, and do these scores e.g. differ substantially from those of the World Bank?
